# How do i select/activate multiple sheets to transfer Userform data into cells?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have checkboxes in Userform and depdning on which checkboxes are selected i want to select/activate excel sheets corresponding to the checkboxes.

Ex. Checkbox A, B, C is clicked i want to select/activate tabs A,B,C so i can trasnfer information to those sheets. I know how to trasnfer data but i'm unsure how to select multiple sheets given the condition of checkboxes.

```
If A_Checkbox.value = True Then
Cells(emptyRow, 1).value=NOD_Text.value
```

but the problem is i have about 8 checkboxes and i'm unsure how to transfer data into multiple sheets depending on which checkboxes are clicked...

Is there a function where I can say "If any checkboxes values are true then transfer userform data into corresponding sheets?

---

so i've used the code from the response but i can't seem to get it to work? (i'm not very familiar with vba..sorry...)

```
Private Sub Add_Button_Click ()
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
      If TypeName(ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
    Transfervalues ctrl, emptyRow
End If
Next
End Sub

Function Transfervalues(cb As MSForms.CheckBox, emptyRow As Long)
Dim ws As Worksheet

     If cb Then
        Select Case cb.Name
            Case "A"
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("A").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
           Case "B"
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("B").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "C"
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("C").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "D"
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("D").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "E"
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("E").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "F"
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("F").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "G"
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("G").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
          Case "H"
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               Sheets("H").Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
     End Select
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Try `Select Case Left(cb.Name, 1)`. Also I will make some revisions to mine based on what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your checkbox objects named `A_Checkbox`, `B_Checkbox`, etc., correspond to worksheets named exactly like `"A"`, `"B"`, etc., then something like:

```
Private Sub Add_Button_Click()
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        'Pass this CheckBox to the subroutine below:
        TransferValues ctrl
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**REVISED**

It looks like you are dumping the same data from the user form to each sheet, based on the check box selection(s). You won't need a case select statement for this, just define a `worksheet` variable based on the `CheckBox.Name`. Note that I changed this from a `Function` to a `Sub` although that shouldn't matter really.  I also change this so the value of `emptyRow` is calculated *each time*, since that will change depending on what worksheet you are acting on.

```
Sub TransferValues(cb As MSForms.CheckBox)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim emptyRow as Long

    If cb Then
       'Define the worksheet based on the CheckBox.Name property:
        Set ws = Sheets(Left(cb.Name, 1))
        emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A:A")) + 1
           With ws
               .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = NOD_Text.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TOD_Text.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Program_Text.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = email_Text.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = OPN_Text.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = CPN_Text.Value
           End With
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit to clarify based on comments from OP**

`TypeName` is a built-in method that returns a string that identifies the *type* of object.  In this case, we iterate over *all* controls on the user form, so you need some logic to make sure the function only operates on the `CheckBox` controls.

`cb` is a variable local to the `TransferValues` subroutine.  In the calling subroutine (`CommandButton1_Click` in my example), we send the object `ctrl` (a CheckBox control) to this subroutine.

The boolean statement `If cb` simply evaluates whether the checkbox has been checked. You could do `If cb.Value = True` but my personal preference is to simplify it.

**UPDATED & TESTED**

Here is a Before picture with an example userform containing three checkboxes and a few dummy textboxes:

[image]

Now here is the worksheet "C" after I have pressed the "Add" button:

[image]

And finally, I can continue to change the textbox values and press the add button over and over again, like so:

[image]

Comment: with all respect but this isn't what the op is asking(or is it?) he wants to select multiple sheets and transfer the data to all of them at once. I mean I understood it like that but some clarification from OP would be nice.

Comment: @mehow clarification would be good. I understood this as a 1:1 relationship between CheckBox/Worksheet. This should loop each checkbox in the form. I'll make a small revision though since there may need to some additional logic.

Comment: @DavidZemens I've tried the following coding but I can't get it to work... I'm not very familiar with excel. i don't really understand the TypeName(ctrl) = "Checkbox" part as well as the meaning of cb.. i understand the cases but i don't understand other statements...

Comment: see revisions & comments to my answer.

Comment: I tried using the revised coding that you have provided but it highlights Set ws = Sheets(LEft(cb.Name,1)) and gives me an error "Subscription out of range" how should I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you have a worksheet in the active workbook that corresponds with the first letter of that CheckBox's `.Name` property. That's your fault, not mine :)  You indicated worksheet names like `"A"` and checkbox names like `"A_CheckBox"`, etc.

Comment: I've made sure that worksheet name is same as the checkbox name as you have indicated "A" for "A_CheckBox" and it doesn't prompt error anymore, but when i click Add button on my userform it doesn't add anything...? please help!

Comment: What is `NOD_Text`? Is this a Range object or a component/control on the UserForm?  If it is a Range object, make sure the range has been assigned properly (nothing in the two subroutines above does this) and that it has a non-empty value.

Comment: All those _Texts are the textboxes in the UserForm and their (Name) in the properties is NOD_Text adn etc. so the info entered into the text box is transferred to an emptyrow at column 1,2,3 etc...

Comment: If it's not working for you, you're doing something wrong -- maybe you mistyped something or did not copy all of the code correctly, etc.   So make sure that you have copied the code from the answer *exactly*, as it has been revised a few times you may have omit something...Otherwise, the answer is right here, I mean, I can show you that it's working so now it's kinda your responsibility to troubleshoot why you haven't been able to implement it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to David Zemens!

I had to make a slight modification to his code because I couldn't paste across multiple sheets based on checkbox selection.

See modified code below - now I can select any of my checkboxes and the save button pastes into the emptyrow in every sheet.

```
Private Sub    
Dim cb As Control    
Dim ws As Worksheet    
Dim emptyRow As Long

For Each cb In UserForm3.Controls

    If TypeName(cb) = "CheckBox" Then
        'Pass this CheckBox to the subroutine below:
        If cb Then
        Set ws = Sheets(Left(cb.Name, 2))
        emptyRow = (WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A7:A5000")) + 6) + 1
           With ws
               .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBox6.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value
               .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
           End With
        End If        
    End If
Next cb

Unload UserForm3    
UserForm2.Show    
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUCpi.png)